# Parsing through multiple file contents inside a foreach loop C#

Tags: c#, file-io, streamwriter

I have a CSV file that I read using LumenWorks CSV, inside the CSV I have multipole filepaths, I have written the program to extract the file paths from CSV like:

```
while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < headers.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(csv[i], 
            @"^(?:[a-zA-Z]\:|\\\\[\w\.]+\\[\w.$]+)\\(?:[\w]+\\)*\w([\w.])+$"))
        {
            string[] individualFilePaths = csv[i].Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, 
                StringSplitOptions.None);

            foreach (var s in individualFilePaths)
            {
                ReadFileContents(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem comes when i call ReadFile Contents method,I want the files to be read individually, how do I do that , here is the program:

```
public void ReadFileContents(string fpath)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fpath))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            list.Add(line);
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing is jumping out as incorrect at first glance... what is the current behavior, compared to the desired behavior, when this is run with your csv and the corresponding files?

Comment: Hi Chris, Say we have 4 file paths returned by  the CSVReader , I want to write these files individually to the console using function(ReadFileContents(string fpath)), in the current scenario contents of all the four files have been written in bulk to console

Comment: Should you be splitting on the comma character? It's still not exactly clear to me what the actual output is. Please modify your question with an example of the `.csv` file contents (a line or two), the actual output of your program that's incorrect, and what you expect that output to be.

Comment: Also, just FYI, you might consider using the `File` class to read files (it wraps the `StreamReader` stuff nicely). In `ReadFileContents` you could do : `var list = File.ReadAllLines(fpath);` to get all the lines in one shot, and you could do `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list));` to write the file lines to the console. (or more efficiently, you could do `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fpath))
{
    list.Add(line);
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}`)

Comment: Hi Rufus,  Thanks for the suggestion.CSV File has a path column that has file paths for files with diff extensions. My desired output:

    *for Email.txt        ---- show email content separately
    *for customer.csv     ---- show csv content separately
    
or when writing of email is over, save that to a separate variable

Current output: 

All the four files read simultaneously without any distinction. Read one after another making it hardly readable.

Comment: If that is the issue, would just adding a title at the start of each file make things clearer? and possibye a footer a the end?
`Console.WriteLine(fpath); using(){...} Console.WriteLine("---end---");`

Comment: Hi Chris, Resolved it, the files are sent from external apps could not change header and footer. But I got a workaround I called the desired function that I wanted also inside that for each. Thanks for the help :)